# Multiplication using numbers as strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

Here is the code that I have wrote :

```
int MulHugeNumbers(char *a1, char *a2,char *res){

int carry=0,len1,len2,*ip,foo,i,count = 0;
char bar[4096],add[50],*cp=bar;

ip = &carry ;
if ((checkifnum(a1) == 0)||(checkifnum(a2) == 0)) return 0;
len1 = strlen(a1) - 1;
len2 = strlen(a2) - 1;
foo = len2 ;
a1 += strlen(a1) - 1;
a2 += strlen(a2) - 1;
do{
    do{
        multinums(a1,a2,cp,ip) ;
        cp++,len1--;   
        if (len1!=-1) a1--;
    }while(len1>-1) ;
    if (carry > 0) *cp++ = (char)(carry + '0');
    carry = 0,len1 = strlen(a1) - 1,a1 += strlen(a1) - 1;
    if(--len2>-1){
        a2--;
        for(i=0; i<foo-len2; i++){
            *cp++ = '0';
        }   
    }
} while(len2>-1) ;
if (carry > 0) *cp++ = (char)(carry + '0');
*cp = '\0' ;
strrev(bar) ;
printf("%s\n",bar) ;
return 1;
}
```

I have created an array and I have stored the result of every digit multiplication,but I need to split the string and make additions for each seperated multiplication in order to have the final result that I will save to the *res pointer. I have the algorithm that adds two strings and gives the output but I don't know how to split the string in order to do so. Any ideas?

for example when i multiply 127*215 I store the result in an array called bar as : 254001270635. To explain, 635 is the result of 5*127,1270 is the result of 1*127 plus the one zero at the very end in order to add 1270+635 and 25400 is the result of 2*127 plus the two zeros to make the final addition...my problem is that i haven't find a way to split the long string to those 3 different ones

Comment: Split a string based on what criterion? A separator character, or after a certain number of characters?

Comment: If you seriously write code like that, I'm not reading it.

Comment: @Evert for example if you multiply 127*215 the first multiplication gives you 635 the second 1270(and I add one zero to the end) and the third 254(00) so I want to add those three strings that I have stored in the same array. In order to do so i need to split the array to those three number.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh what's the problem with my code exactly?

Comment: missing indentation and whitespacing....

Comment: So you want to split the string "127*215" into "127", "2", "1" and "5"? It's still unclear how (and what) you precisely want to split.

Comment: @SouravGhosh just don't read it then, and move on. I would rather complain about missing braces about single-line in if-statements, which have lead to nasty bugs.

Comment: not really but every opinion is valid...

Comment: @Evert Yeah, without even trying to educate about the mistake? So what happens when 10 more of those hard to read formatting comes up?

Comment: @SouravGhosh your first comment was not educational. Only after the OP asked, you mentioned what was wrong. Had you written "please consider using proper indentation and whitespace use" as your first comment, the OP might have gotten a better idea. Now, it's just a lose remark doing nothing.

Comment: @Evert No when i multiply 127*215 I store the result in an array as : 254001270635. To explain, 635 is the result of 5*127,1270 is the result of 1*127 plus the one zero at the very end in order to add 1270+635 and 25400 is the result of 2*127 plus the two zeros to make the final addition...my problem is that i haven't find a way to split the long string to those 3 different ones

Comment: @ADS perhaps you should add your (precise) example in the question; that will help more than the current amount of code and a somewhat vague description.

Comment: Can't you store the string with a separator, such as a space: "25400 1270 635". Why do you need to store it as a string?: 3 (long) ints would also work.

Comment: @Evert the program is supposed to be able to handle very big numbers given as strings and multiply them as strings.My problem is how to use strtok to split the big string or any other way to do so...

Comment: Just keep track of the length of the final substring when you're creating that long string (call it `n`). Then, your first substring has length `n` and runs from 0 to `n` (0-based), the second runs from `n` to `n+n-1`, the third from `n+n-1` to `n+n-1+n-2` etc; until you run past the length of the long string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [Strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) can help you 'tokenize' the string, which means separating each of the 'substrings' that compose it.